# Blocked port 22 but still have root access to ftp

Tags: ssh, ftp, ufw

recently I messed up hard and blocked port 22 with ufw, but I still have root access with sftp. I tried editing `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` and set `ENABLED=no` but even after reboot I still cant connect. Any suggestion ? I also know that port 25566 is opened, can I maybe somehow change ssh to that port ?

Also with putty i get this:

[image: Error]

Update: I logged into ssh with port 2226(sftp port) and disabled ufw.
I still cant login with port 22

Looks like problem is not in ufw, also looks like no service is running on port 22, any suggestion?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: ftp (21) is not sftp (22) – not really an answer to your question, but mistaking those two only complicates understanding of your problem.

Comment: Did you change anything in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

Comment: better check out system logs (syslog, message) and grep for sshd related errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missedited sshd_config, after I added this to the config, problem was solved:

1. Port 22
2. AddressFamily any
3. ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
4. ListenAddress ::